# Laravel 5.2 login message custom

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am kind of new to Laravel framework, working on 5.2. I run

```
php artisan make:auth()
```

Now I am trying to custom the error message on the login form "these credentials do not match our records"

I tried to override the failLoginMessage() method in AuthController.php but it's not working. One more thing the password field error message is not working at all even though I enter the right email but wrong password the validation runs on email field but not on password field.

Comment: It might be different between versions, but in 5.4, the string you're looking for is in `/resources/lang/en/auth.php`. If it's somewhere else in 5.2, try searching your project for the string itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can't see your code, check this out: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/resources/lang/en/auth.php, this is on branch `5.2` in Github, that is the lang file, you can define a new folder inside of lang directory named `es` and make inside it an `auth.php`, if you feel good and warm in terminal `cd <your_proy_dir> && mkdir -p resources/lang/es/ && touch resources/lang/es/auth.php`, and define a fundamentals key inside that file:

```
'failed' => 'Estos credenciales no coinciden con ninguno almacenado.',
```

That would be for spanish, but is the same principle for every language, then, to change your application language, you just have to go to the `config/app.php` and change this:

```
 'locale' => 'en',
```

for this:

```
 'locale' => 'es',
```

Once again, this is for spanish, but is the same principle.

Good luck.
Cheers! ;)

Comment: It's working but only for the email address field, even if i write the right email address but the wrong password the "has-error" class is added to the email field and the error appears beneath the email address field .. if sharing my code could help what would i have to share ? please please help :(

Comment: P.S : sorry for the delay had to renew internet subscription and stuff :)